# How Facebook username works?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, redirect, url-rewriting

First of all this is not just about redirecting. I'm trying to understand the facebook username structure completely. So don't tell me to use htaccess, I already know that.

```
facebook.com/profile.php?id = username
facebook.com/profile.php?id = id

facebook.com/username
facebook.com/id
```

These urls do the same thing and redirect you to the

```
facebook.com/username
```

If a user trying to use the user id, it checks the user id from db and fetchs the user name and redirects the user to the facebook.com/username.

So far, so good.

All the user made activities are stored to db with user id, but while printing the data, links are turned into user names. So, they should be fetching the username data with every query they made. And while processing the data user names turns into user ids. Finally, If the user don't set a user name user id still works.

This is what I understand till now. Here are my questions.

- How should I store the user names in db?
- I think this structure will cause lots of performance issues for my queries. Will it?
- This need lots of changes on a working system. Do you think is there an easy way to do it? (Somethink like detecting and redirecting the id's to php page which turns them into user name)
- Handling the users which haven't have user names seems a big problem to me. How to overcome it?
  **Update:**
- How to determine coming url is containing user id or a user name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Store it as a nullable column in the user table
2. It shouldn't. You are only grabbing one extra column, and if you are really worried, grab it one time, then keep it stored in a variable
3. In a well designed working system, the logic should all be in the "User" class, so it shouldn't be hard. If it requires lots of changes, then your code needs to be refactored and cleaned up to have the logic in one place
4. Well, with the logic all in the user class, you have a single method that returns the display name, and if the user has a user name, you return the user name version, otherwise, use the id version

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Keeping the user name as a row in users table will create lots of empty rows. Won't it be a problem? One last thing. I updated the question

Comment: I don't see why having lots of empty rows is much of a problem. If you are scaling the size of Facebook, then you may need better optimizations, but that won't be an issue right away. You'll have to parse the incoming URL parameters to figure out if they are a # or a string to identify the type of URL. Most web development frameworks have the ability to handle this for you.